# array picking by percent

Tags: php, arrays

Quick question which is probably very simple, yet I cannot find an answer to it :/

What's an easier way to do this?

```
//This is a array we set to let the server pick if the pokemon is normal or shiny or ice
$randomview = array( "Ice","Shiny","Shiny","Shiny","Shiny","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal");

// here we shuffle them up to make it fair
shuffle($randomview);
```

How do I generate one of the results randomly, but keep them weighted like in the example?

Updated with answer.

```
$type1 = array_fill(1,1000,"Normal");
$type2 = array_fill(1,5,"Ice");
$type3 = array_fill(1,2,"Shiny");
$randomview97 = array_merge($type1, $type2, $type3);
// here we shuffle them up to make it fair
shuffle($randomview97);
```

Comment: Normal, or Shiny, or... Ice? How'd you manage to put "Ice" in the same category as "Normal" and "Shiny"? Just curious :P

Comment: I made my own sprites for them. XD

Comment: I think you'll like [anime.se].

Comment: What exactly is the question ??/

Comment: I know there is a simpler way to do the array instead of putting Normal 500 times lol.

Comment: @user1908445: Have a look at the question I've linked.

Comment: ahh, thanks I guess I'll just keep it the way I have it since the other weighted way seems more complicated :/ thanks for the help though!

Comment: Your last comment brings me back to a question that first popped into my mind while reading your question: *"Define easier"*.

Comment: Perhaps try the `wrand`-function by [Justin Hileman](http://justinhileman.info/article/wrand-a-php-weighted-randomization-function/)

Comment: array_fill(1,500,"Normal") which you array_merge with the others in the array.

Comment: Thank you very much @ cups just what I needed :)